# Given a matrix C, calculate $e^C e^{C^T}$ and $e^{-C}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given:

$$\mathcal C=\pmatrix{-5&3&-3\\2&-4&1\\2&-2&-1}$$

Calculate: $e^C e^{C^T}$

Calculate: $e^{-C}$

I am using the formula $\mathcal f(C)=\mathcal S f(\lambda)\mathcal S^{-1}$, therefore I used Matlab to calculate $det(\lambda I-\mathcal C)=0$ to get my eigenvalues:

$\lambda_1=-5$, $\lambda_2=-3$ and $\lambda_3=-2$.

For $\lambda_1=-5$:

$$U_1=\pmatrix{-2&-1&-1\\0&-3&3\\0&0&0}$$

For $\lambda_2=-3$:

$$U_2=\pmatrix{2&-3&3\\0&-2&2\\0&0&0}$$

But for $\lambda_3=-2$:

$$U_3=\pmatrix{3&-3&3\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}$$

Therefore:

$$\Lambda=\pmatrix{-5&0&0\\0&-3&0\\0&0&-2}$$

And $$S=\pmatrix{-1&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&1&0}$$

Which gives a nonexistent $\mathcal S^{-1}$ !!  Could someone please tell me what went wrong?  I should be able to calculate the exponentials this way.....or is there another way to deal with this problem?  Any help is greatly appreciated as always.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, you need to compute only $e^{C}$ in full details, then you can use relations between the eigenvalues of a matrix and its transpose. Here is the final answer you need to reach

> $$e^{C} =\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} {{\rm e}^{-5}}&-{{\rm e}^{-5}}+{{\rm e}^{-
> 2}}&-{{\rm e}^{-2}}+{{\rm e}^{-5}}\\{{\rm e}^{-3}}-
> {{\rm e}^{-5}}&{{\rm e}^{-5}}+{{\rm e}^{-2}}-{{\rm e}^{-3}}&-{{\rm e}^
> {-2}}+2\,{{\rm e}^{-3}}-{{\rm e}^{-5}}\\{{\rm e}^{-
> 3}}-{{\rm e}^{-5}}&-{{\rm e}^{-3}}+{{\rm e}^{-5}}&2\,{{\rm e}^{-3}}-{
> {\rm e}^{-5}}\end {array} \right] .$$

Comment: ~ would you explain the steps that you took please?  Especially if you didn't use $\mathcal f(C)=Sf(\lambda)S^{-1}$.

Comment: @Lanae Why did you accept this answer?

Comment: @Artem~  I thought it was correct, but now I'm second guessing that decision.  I tried to calculate $e^Ce^{C^T}$ and $e^{-C}$ using the expm command in Matlab afterwards and was able to get some results.    I put $C$ in and got $C^T$ and $C^{-1}$ then for part a) I set $D=(C+C^T)$ and got $expm(D)$. For part b) I set $D=-C$ and got $expm(D)$.  I'm hoping that is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you solved $U_3x=0$ wrongly. As $U_3$ is singular, it has a nontrivial solution, like $(1,1,0)^T$, for instance.

Comment: ~ That's what is driving me crazy.  I can't figure it out.  I did it by hand and by Matlab.  Got the same answer for $U_3$ and my eigenvector is all zeros.  Its probably something so stupid....this is the second problem using the same procedure where this is happening.  :(

Comment: For an equation like Ux=b with $b\neq0$, one can solve it by the Matlab command x=U\b. However, when b=0, it seems that Matlab hasn't any support to find a *nontrivial* solution x. What have you done with Matlab, actually?

Comment: ~I asked Matlab to give me the $det(\lambda I-C)$ and it gave me $\lambda^3+10\lambda^2+31\lambda+30=0$ with $\lambda_1=-5$, $\lambda_2=-3$ and $\lambda_3=-2$.  I plugged the $\lambda$ values in the $\lambda I-C$ matrix and asked Matlab to give me the LU decomp to use the U matrices to solve for the eigenvectors.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: ~ problem is I have that $U_3$ that has the eigenvector of zeros.  I'm hoping that someone can help with that.

Comment: Well, as I said in the answer, by simple inspection, one sees that $x=(1,1,0)^T$ is a nontrivial solution to $U_3x=0$, i.e. $x$ is an eigenvector of $C$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$. Actually I just learnt that you can cheat with Matlab: the command null(U3) will give you the null space of U3, hence any column output by this command will be an eigenvector for the zero eigenvalue.

Comment: ~ Thank you so much for the help.  I'll give the Matlab cheat a try as well.  :)

Comment: @Lanae: Why not just use http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/eig.html? I do not use Matlab, but recall that command.

Comment: @Amzoti and user1551~ I actually used the expm command in Matlab and did the calculations.  Using the null command still gave me an empty set, so I took a shot with the expm command.  Worked really nice!!  The  null command however did give me my final eigenvector in the other question that I'm working using the concept that I wanted to use for this problem.  Matlab is the preferred choice it seems in most of my classes thus far and in my project work.